# How to wrap a method (with a parameter list) to be executes on the thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have a methode that looks like:

```
public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
  return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

I want to wrap this method by a delegate that is invoked by a thread, How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. `Random` class isn't thread safe. Accessing it from multiple threads needs synchronization, or avoid sharing of `random` instance.  2.What you have tried and where is the problem?

Comment: The Thread class has constructors that they don't take parameters, this is my problen?

Comment: You can work around it with lambda and closures. But, be sure you read my first point about thread safety

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a delegate that doesn't take any parameters, create a thread around this delegate, and when that delegate is called, it will call that method with a specific set of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "wrap", anyway you can reference the method using a `Func` delegate:

```
Func<int, int, int> myDelegate = RandomNumber;
```

then you can call it like this:

```
int rnd = myDelegate(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be your thread code:

```
private Thread thread;

public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min, max);
}

public void RandomNumberProc(object state)
{
    int[] array = state as int[];
    RandomNumber(array[0], array[1]);
}

prublic void StartThread()
{
    thread = new Thread(RandomNumberProc);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start(new[] { 1, 2 });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you write this: RandomNumber(array[0], array[1]); and this: thread.Start(new[] { 1, 2 }); - Are they an examples or what?